# How can I make my bootcamp partition bootable again after upgrading to El Capitan?

Tags: macos, boot, boot-camp

I recently upgraded to El Capitan OSX 10.11 and now can't boot into Windows.

If I restart the computer and hold Option down, the only option is OSX. If I use System Preferences to select the bootcamp partition as the startup disk, and then restart without the option key, I get

```
No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key.
```

I tried booting with VMware Fusion 8.0.1 and got a slightly different response (see image)

[image: Snapshot of VMware]

From what I've read, I may need to repair the MBR.  Here is some investigation I ran `sudo gpt -v -r show /dev/disk0`

```
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=750156374016; sectorsize=512; blocks=1465149168
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  1268157456      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1268567096     1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  1269836632        1192         
  1269837824   195309568      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  1465147392        1743         
  1465149135          32         Sec GPT table
  1465149167           1         Sec GPT header
```

And I ran `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0`

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 91201/255/63 [1465149168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 - 1465149167] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Some things I have tried without success include

- Using rEFIt. There seems to be a problem running this on El Capitan.
- Using `sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk0`. The write command fails with `fdisk: /dev/disk0: Operation not permitted`. Same result for `sudo disk -i /dev/disk0`.

My question. How can I make my bootcamp partition bootable again?

Comment: Perhaps I should mention that I am using full disk encryption in the Mac Partition. I have no idea if this is relevant.

Comment: Apparently you may need to give Terminal more permissions to get `fdisk`/`gpt`/etc working on `/dev/diskN`: https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Answer (score 0):

Try using rEFInd instead of rEFIt. It's resolved multi-boot issues for me.

You can install Ubuntu for triple booting Windows, Mac and Ubuntu.

[This](http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/) article has some pointers.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I'd prefer not to install yet another OS if I can help it.  For getting rEFInd to work under El Capitan the following might be useful http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209272/how-do-i-get-refind-working-with-os-x-10-11-el-capitan .